# LocalTime methods returning integers that do not make sense

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have this function that I am supposed to write that returns a `Collection<String>`. It has 3 parameters: `LocalTime startDate`, `LocalTime endDate`, and `Collection<String> logLines`. I am supposed to write the function body so that it successfully finds and removes any lines from the log that are not within a specific timeframe defined by `startDate` and `endDate` and then returns that log.

The plan is to get the hours, minutes, and seconds from `endDate` and `startDate` using `LocalTime` methods `getHour()`, `getMinute()`, and `getSecond()`, and convert to seconds to see how many seconds elapsed at the start of the timeframe and how many elapsed by the end of the timeframe. I then iterate over all of the Strings in `logLines`. They are in the format: `2012-05-11T02:11:44Z    This program did this operation successfully.`. I split each string to get the first part of the line and parse it using `LocalTime.parse()` in the `ISO_DATE_TIME` format to obtain the date and store it in `LocalTime logDate`. Finally, I use the same `LocalTime` methods listed above to get the total seconds elapsed up to this log time.

The problem I am having is that when I use the `LocalTime` methods it's storing all of the same numbers over and over again no matter what `startDate`, `endDate`, or `logDate` is. I have never used Java 8, or any Java library, before this so I cannot think of why or how it is doing this. I know that when `startDate` and `endDate` are passed they are also strings in the same format as the log date parsed using `LocalDate.parse()` and the `ISO_DATE_TIME` format.

```
public Collection<String> search(Collection<String> logLines, LocalTime startDate, LocalTime endDate) {

    // format date extracted from logLines to same format as startDate and endDate 
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

    // total seconds elapsed at startDate
    // total seconds elapsed by endDate
    int startSeconds = startDate.getHour() * 60 * 60;     
    startSeconds    += startDate.getMinute() * 60; 
    startSeconds    += startDate.getSecond();

    int endSeconds = endDate.getHour() * 60 * 60;
    endSeconds    += endDate.getMinute() * 60;
    endSeconds    += endDate.getSecond();

    // iterate through logLines
    int i = 0;
    for(String logLine : logLines) {            

        // array of strings to separate logLine into parts
        String[] line = new String[2];
        line          = logLine.split("\t");

        // localTime object to store extracted date from logLines
        LocalTime logDate = LocalTime.parse(line[0], formatter);             

        // get seconds elapsed from logDate
        int logDateSeconds = logDate.getHour() * 60 * 60;
        logDateSeconds    += logDate.getMinute() * 60;
        logDateSeconds    += logDate.getSecond();

        // print amount of seconds to console
        System.out.print(logDateSeconds);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(startSeconds);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(endSeconds);
        System.out.print("\n");

        if (logDateSeconds > endSeconds || logDateSeconds < startSeconds) {

            logLines.remove(i);
            i--;

        }

        i++;

    }

    return logLines;

}
```

When I print out `startSeconds`, `endSeconds`, and `logDateSeconds` to the console I get

```
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
12114 12116 12122
```

no matter what the inputs are.

Please point me in the right direction.

Sample input:

`logLines` contains

```
2012-05-11T02:11:44Z    This program did this operation successfully.
2012-05-11T02:12:52Z    This program did this operation successfully.
2012-05-11T02:14:17Z    This program did this operation successfully.
2012-05-11T02:18:02Z    This program did this operation successfully.
2012-05-11T02:20:30Z    This program did this operation successfully.
```

`startDate = 02:11:44` and `endDate = 02:19:57`

Comment: You're creating a new array for no reason. Just do `String[] line = logLine.split("\t");`.

Comment: so, `startSeconds` and `endSeconds` will not change, so the only relavant part of your code is `LocalTime logDate = LocalTime.parse(line[0], formatter);`  - what is the input?

Comment: That's the way I was doing it before, but unaware if that might have caused an issue I changed it.

Comment: You're asking us to believe that varying `startDate` and `endDate` doesn't change `startSeconds` and `endSeconds`? Personally I'm a little skeptical.

Comment: When the function is called, ``startDate`` and ``endDate`` remain the same until the end of the function. It's meant to be used like a search function.

Comment: @ScaryWombat ``logDate`` should change as ``logLine`` changes

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I suggest that you debug your code at the area that I mentioned above.

Comment: `logLines.remove(i)` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @shmosel Ah! Thank you. I changed my for loop from for-each to a regular for loop and then ``Iterator<String> logLine = logLines.iterator()`` and then used ``logLine.next()`` to get the string and ``logLine.remove()`` to remove strings i didn't want and it works now.

Comment: @Luke Your approach seems convoluted, you seem to be working too hard. You have instants in the timeline, which should be parsed as `Instant` objects. But you are chopping up pieces into `LocalDate` and `LocslTime` objects which purposely have no time zone. So your time-of-day values only have meaning within UTC. I suggest you post another Question about what you are trying to accomplish so we can address your approach. Please post an Answer to this Question so we can close it as it seems your immediate issue was resolved.

Comment: @BasilBourque I would use ``Instant`` but the class isn't available to me. The environment is controlled. The only classes I have are ``java.time.LocalTime`` and ``java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter``. I also tried parsing using ``DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT``, but I get a ``DateTimeParseException`` that says ``Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor`` which makes sense. I solved the issue where it was not removing the line from ``logLines``, but now my issue is that in one of the cases the string is not being parsed because of the format. but I can't use ``DateTimeParseException``.

Comment: `Instant` is in the same package alongside `LocalTime`. No reason to not use it as well as `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque That's what I thought too, but when I use them I get ``Cannot find symbol`` error. I fixed the problem and everything is working as it should. I just have to upload the solution and change the status of the question. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my initial question was in the way I was using `for(String logLine : logLines)` to iterate over logLines. I changed it to `for(Iterator<String> logLine = logLines.iterator(); logLine.hasNext(); )`. This is thanks to [shmosel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477793/localtime-methods-returning-integers-that-do-not-make-sense?noredirect=1#comment68200424_40477793) on how I was using `logLines.remove(i)`. Before coming to that conclusion  I noticed that the dates in `logLines` were instants and I attempted to use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`, but `LocalTime` could not parse the time, which makes sense. I also tried creating `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `Instant` objects, but they all returned the error `Cannot find symbol`. I don't know why this is exactly because this is my first run-around with Java 8, and Java in general. The only classes that were made available to me to manipulate time were `java.time.LocalTime` and  `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`. [Basil Bourque states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477793/localtime-methods-returning-integers-that-do-not-make-sense?noredirect=1#comment68227893_40477793) that `Instant` is in the same package as `LocalTime` and `ZonedLocalTime`, which I thought the same, but clearly those classes were not accessible to me in this project. I also tried using `isBefore()`, `isAfter()`, and `equals()`, but they didn't function as I expected and I figured it was unnecessary if I can calculate the seconds elapsed.

I then ran into another issue where I was getting an `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format` error. This was interesting because I could not see the input or the output of the test case and I had no idea what an `Exception` was. I assumed the problem was that `logLine.next()` did not contain a date or time. To fix this I fumbled with `try` and `catch` blocks, trying to use `DateTimeParseException` with no success. I got the same `Cannot find symbol` error as before. Then I realized there must be a generic `Exception` class and that fixed the issue. Everything works as it should.

Here is the corrected code, which is much smaller and easier to read:

```
public Collection<String> search(Collection<String> logLines, LocalTime startDate, LocalTime endDate) {

    // DateTimeFormatter same as startDate and endDate
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

    // total seconds elapsed at startDate
    // total seconds elapsed at endDate
    int startSeconds = startDate.toSecondOfDay();
    int endSeconds   = endDate.toSecondOfDay();

    // iterate through logLines
    for(Iterator<String> logLine = logLines.iterator(); logLine.hasNext(); ) {

        // split logLine into two strings: logDate, logDescription
        // store in string array `line`
        String[] line = logLine.next().split("\t");

        // int for storing amount of seconds from logDate
        int logDateSeconds;

        // try to parse logDate
        // catch generic exception to avoid parsing error
        try {

            // parse logDate using ISO_DATE_TIME formatter
            // get amount of seconds to compare to startSeconds and endSeconds
            logDateSeconds = LocalTime.parse(line[0], formatter).toSecondOfDay();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // continue to next iteration for any Exception
            continue;

        }


        // compare amount of seconds to see if it is within time frame
        if (logDateSeconds >= endSeconds || logDateSeconds < startSeconds) {

            // remove iteration if it is not within time frame
            logLine.remove();
        }

    }

    // return edited 
    return logLines;

}
```